# Need help converting SQL Query to Ruby.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to determine the proper ruby query for the following SQL query. The following query works but I'm wondering what the most Railsy way to do this is.

```
@user_urls = Url.find_by_sql(["
select urls.* 
from urls 
join connections on connections.id = urls.connection_id 
join users on users.id = connections.user_id 
where urls.marked_for_sending = true and users.id = ?", @user.id])
```

Here are some details about my model associations -

```
User has many Connections
Connection has many URLs
Connection belongs to User
URL belongs to Connection
```

Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an association in the User model:

```
#user.rb
has_many :urls, :through => :connections

@user_urls = @user.urls.where(marked_for_sending: true)
```

Other option:

```
@user_urls = Url.joins(:connection).where(connections: {user: @user}).where(marked_for_sending: true)
```

Comment: Wonderful! That makes life much easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joins` and `where` in rails

```
@user_urls = Url.joins("LEFT JOIN connections ON connections.id = urls.connection_id").joins(" LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = connections.user_id").where("urls.marked_for_sending =? AND users.id = ?", true, @user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is create a `has_many through:` connection between `User` and `Url`, then create a scope for `Url` to fetch `marked_for_sending`. Something like:

#### models

```
class User
  has_many :connections
  has_many :urls, through: :connections
end

class Url
  scope :marked_for_sending, where(marked_for_sending: true)
end
```

#### usage

```
@user_urls = @user.urls.marked_for_sending
```

**note:** this *might* require some tweaking, so let me know if you have any issues implementing and I'll update the answer.